# System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.' when trying to download data from google server

Tags: c#, image, google-maps, google-api, webclient

I'm using a WebClient to download images from cbk0.google.com but I've started to get the error `System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.'` every time. I made about 200000 requests that all worked correctly as a test and since then every request I make results in this exception. I can however view the url just fine in my browser. Have I exceeded the amount of requests google allows a single user to make in 24 hours? Do they have a limit? Is there a way around the limit if there is one?

The error may be mine so here is my code:

```
Image[,] images = new Image[26, 13];
        Parallel.For(0, 26, x => {
            Parallel.For(0, 13, y => {
                    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                        images[x, y] = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(client.DownloadData(Get.TileURL(panoID, x, y))));
            });
        });
```

Get.TileUrl:

```
public static string TileURL(string panoID, int x, int y, int zoomLevel = 5)
    {
        return "http://cbk0.google.com/cbk?output=tile&panoid=" + panoID + "&zoom=" + zoomLevel + "&x=" + x + "&y=" + y;
    }
```

I tried catching the exception to see if it  was a one time thing but it resulted in the same exception for every single request.

[Here](https://pastebin.com/nSEJ5M9M) is the network log for the code seen above and [here](https://pastebin.com/DrJmuWZZ) is the log file when it is running in a standard for loop.

Things I've tried:

- Clearing my DNS cache
- Deleting my browser cookies
- Clearing my browser cache

Comment: I would use a sniffer to see if you can capture the issue which will give more info than the exception message in c#.  It is possible the server thought your code was a service attack and locked out requests from your IP.  It is also possible a cookie got corrupted.  So I would manually go to your IE and delete cookies.  The same cookies are used by the IE and the c# code.  Then try again and see if you can download.

Comment: I deleted my cookies and no luck.

Comment: @jdweng I've never used a sniffer before. Do you have any suggestions for a good one?

Comment: Either wireshark or fiddler.  Both you can download for free.

Comment: [Here](https://pastebin.com/nSEJ5M9M) is my network log.

Comment: I guessing.  But it looks like you are running in parallel from logs and the server is only allowing 8 connections at one time.   The 9th "Create" is failing.  Make sure you dispose the WebClient after you receive each response to make sure the connection closes.  The "using" statement in your code should dispose.

Comment: I tried to run it in a normal for loop but to no avail.

Comment: Did the log files change?

Comment: You are failing the proxy step on first request : System.Net Error: 0 : [14264] Can't retrieve proxy settings for Uri 'http://cbk0.google.com/cbk?output=tile&panoid=CAoSLEFGMVFpcE1aOVFRbXVadXNHTWpoX04xSjZLNEZ6Q0pCSE9US1lrZ1dvNFZU&zoom=5&x=0&y=1'. Error code: 12180.

Comment: The new [log file](https://pastebin.com/DrJmuWZZ) is quite different. What should I do for the proxy setup?

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and capture the request when you use your browser when the request works.  There are headers that are missing in your c#.  So compare the request in c# and the request in the browser.

Comment: It's now not working with my browser either. "Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request. "

Comment: The cookie is shared between the browser and your application.  Manually go into your browser and delete cookies and try again.

Comment: Clearing cookies didn't help. It still results in the error.

Comment: Do you have a google account?  Can you login?

Comment: Yes I can login as normal.

Comment: It looks like your locked out if you can't get in using the browser.  It probably will reset after a period of time.  It is also possible the server is down for service.

Comment: I cleared my cache on my browser and it works now but not with my code.

Comment: I also downloaded a panorama from a different program written in js that uses the same method and it works 100% correctly.

Comment: I've now also tried clearing my DNS cache but that didn't work either.

Comment: Capture browser request and compare to c# request.

Comment: I found the cause of the problem. The url only accepts pano ids of a certain type. Thanks for the help anyway though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the kind of pano id I was feeding it. Neither cbk0.google.com nor maps.google.com work with pano ids beginning with `CAoSLEFGMVFpcE` for tile outputs, however these kinds of panos are still valid for google's documented apis.